# Cant upload sketches

Tags: arduino-uno

I started using the arduino as a hobby and it really is quite fun. I took a break for a bit and when I came back I wasnt able to upload a sketch to my UNO. I checked to see if I was using the correct port and programmer and everything seemed fine. Not exactly sure what to do so I was hoping someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the error message I receive every time I try to upload a sketch:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=2341_0043 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_693101 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -verbose C:\Users\User\Desktop\Arduino\Blink\Blink.ino

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=2341_0043 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_693101 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -verbose C:\Users\User\Desktop\Arduino\Blink\Blink.ino

Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.3

Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.3

Detecting libraries used...

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.3\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.3\\variants\\standard" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o nul -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

Generating function prototypes...

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.3\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.3\\variants\\standard" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp" -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

Compiling sketch...

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.3\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.3\\variants\\standard" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o"

Compiling libraries...

Compiling core...

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\wiring_pulse.S.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\WInterrupts.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\wiring_analog.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\wiring.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\wiring_digital.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\hooks.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\wiring_pulse.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\wiring_shift.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\CDC.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\HardwareSerial.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\Print.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\Stream.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\Tone.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\WMath.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\PluggableUSB.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\WString.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\USBCore.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\new.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\abi.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\IPAddress.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\main.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_36096\core\core.a

Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_693101\core\core_arduino_avr_uno_cac111a68e84b6e7f84741aaeecd4f29.a

Linking everything together...

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/core\\core.a" "-LC:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096" -lm

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/Blink.ino.eep"

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/Blink.ino.hex"

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_36096/Blink.ino.elf"

Sketch uses 924 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x33
```

Hope you will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic communications error between the Arduino and your PC, there can be many reasons for this, going through the steps outlined in Juraj's link above may get you closer to the cause. Another thing worth trying is holding down the Arduino reset button until uploading starts then releasing it.

Comment: Still nothing.  I tried everything except trying a new computer or arduino because I only have one of each.  I'm thinking of ordering a new Arduino. Still deciding if it should be another UNO or maybe a Micro or Nano. Thank you so much for helping.